# Typeahead input element styling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a simple textbox input that looks like this:

```
 <input type="text" placeholder="Search for states">
```

and I want to do an autocomplete on it, similar to typeahead. The autocomplete part works, but I want to display in the textbox first suggestion:

For instance, having written "Al" and I get the following suggestions:

Textbox: Al

- Alabama
- Algeria

I want to have in the textbox, as faded text: Al**abama** (the abama to be faded).

How can I do this with jQuery or pure JS? 
Having basically in the same textbox, 2 text styles for 2 substrings?

If there are other methods (e.g. overlaying another transparent text control on it) and you can show me an example that would be great. I cannot change the `input` element (that is a given).

Comment: I've tried to add a div overlay with a faded text (the abama in the example) but I couldn't get them right (how to attach the div to perfectly match the input) and I was thinking if there is a better way (via css or something) to accomplish this. Also I don't want to have the "abama" text to be selectable or something, just to be there to show the user want will be selected if he hits tab.

Comment: What I ment, it's to post you code..

Answer (score 0):

code pen: 
http://codepen.io/mozzi/pen/XKKJWq

this is very slimier to what you need. I've selected text instead of fading it as you can't do half faded text in a text box. let me know what you think.

HTML:

```
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="automplete-1">Type state name: </label>
  <input id="automplete-1" placeholder="U.S. state name">
</div>
```

javascript:

```
$("#automplete-1").autocomplete({
  delay: 0,
  source: UsStateNames,
  response: function(event, ui) {
    var start = $("#automplete-1").val().length;
    $("#automplete-1").val(ui.content[0].value);
    var end = ui.content[0].value.length;
    $("#automplete-1")[0].setSelectionRange(start, end);
  }
});
```

Comment: you can leave the suggestion list under the text box or remove it. I just left it for visibility.